# Solving simultaneous equations in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 equations, with 4 unknowns, a,b,c,e

w = c + 0.43*a

x + g*b = p*c + 2*e

y + 2*a + h*b = q*c + 2*0.43a + e

z + b*i = c*r

What would be the best way to solve this in Excel?

I searched and found that LINEST might be a good function to use, but couldn't get it to work

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535898/how-to-solve-system-of-4-equations-with-four-unknowns

Comment: Perhaps check out the Solver.

Comment: LINEST is used for creating a curve fitting - can't see how it fits here.

Comment: Matrix operations

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite all you formulas in the form

```
 Ai*(a)+Bi*(b)+Ci*(c)+Ei*(e)=Ki
```

Then for each equation fill out a row in the matrix

```
 A1 B1 C1 E1     a      K1
 A2 B2 C2 E2  x  b   =  K2
 A3 B3 C3 E3     c      K3
 A4 B4 C4 E4     e      K4
```

Then use MInverse and MMultiply functions to solve for a,b,c and e

A,B,C,E are the constants multiplying each variable.  Set them to 0 when they are not in the formula, and make sure you carry the negative sign.

i is just a way to represent the equation number.

K is the constant in the equation with out a variable attached to it.

So provided I did the formula rearrangement properly, one possible result would be:

[image]

Cant take it farther than this as numbers would be needed for g, p, h, q, i, and r (not to mention w, x, y, and z).  Though you could set those up in cells so you sheet would automatically update when you entered values.